# is_home não funciona dentro de wp_enqueue_scripts

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou criando um tema e quero especificar quais folhas de estilo serão importadas ao carregar o site, para isso estou usando o hook `wp_enqueue_scripts`. Dentro dessa action eu faço uma verificação para saber se está na página inicial, se é um single ou se é um archive, ou seja, faço um `if(is_home())` com suas variações. Contudo a função is_home está retornando false, embora esteja na página inicial. Já usei `wp_reset_query()`, mas não resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente não está funcionando pq vc definiu uma página principal nas configurações do wordpress, no lugar do `is_home()`, coloque: `is_front_page()`